# Referencing current directory in tmux with sublime text

Tags: tmux, sublime-text-3

In normal shell I could do `subl .` to open the current directory in sublime text, but when I'm in a tmux pane, this doesn't work. Are there anything I need to configure to make tmux works like normal shell.

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean by not work? What happens? Does ST open with a blank window? Does it remember the last project? It doesn't sound like a ST issue. What is the current directory: `echo $PWD`

Comment: @GerardRoche ST just becomes the active windows, but doesn't open the directory I'm in.